# flutter_stripe - change CardFormField labels / text color

Tags: flutter, flutter-stripe

is there a way to change `CardFormField` labels & text color?

```
CardFormField(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    onCardChanged: (CardFieldInputDetails? change) {
        var completed = change != null && change.complete;
    },
    controller: controller,
)
```

CardFormField got a dark theme:

labels & texts are white & dark keyboard. i set black background to see labels.

other fields in screen got light theme & light keyboard background

dark CardFormField (Card number field focus):

[image]

light keyboard and text (Full Name field focus):

[image]

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_stripe/latest/flutter_stripe/CardFormField/style.html

This is the official update from stripe. It is mentioned that we can't change any field other than background colour in iOS but it works in android.